# WebGL Heightmap from array?

Tags: three.js, webgl

Anyone happen to know of an example or can point me in the right direction on rendering a heightmap/terrain in WebGL from a three dimensional array? Basically I have an array that contains data relevant to x and y coordinates and a 'height' (z axis).

Everything I've found (like in the threejs world) shows how to create one dynamically or from a 2d image. Ideally I'd like to have the color of the pixel/particle related to the height. Basically looking to do something like below but in WebGL:

[image]

Comment: Are the points/vertices in your array in a particular order or structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many examples on how to do this already available.
 You can search for `three.js` + `heigthmap`.
Or try `three.js` + `3d graph`.

[Here is something called a **"Graphulus-Function"**](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Graphulus-Function.html) that looks pretty much exactly like what you need.

[Here you can find another interesting reference](http://danni-three.blogspot.se/2013/09/threejs-heightmaps.html).

Without more details on your data it is hard to say if these examples suit your needs...

Check also [this three.js issue 1003 on GitHub: **"Terrain from Heightmap"**](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1003) where there is a discussion about this topic and lots of great examples are mentioned.

Comment: This led me in the right direction. Got a beautiful colorized heightmap working off of AJAX data now. Thank you!